# What is the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I saw the answer for global variable in python but when I write two similar scripts cannot realize the difference between them one is working one is not. Please help me to understand the difference. As I told I read many of the articles about that but something in my head always is suspicious and this causes mistakes time to time.

```
total = 0
def sum(a,b):
   total = a+b
   print ("inner total is:",total)
return total 

sum(19,21)
print ("outter total is:",total)
```

**OUTPUT**

> inner total is: 40 outter total is: 0

```
i = 2 

def a():
    i = i + 2 
    print (i)
    pass

a()
```

**OUTPUT**

---

> UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6     pass
>         7 
>   ----> 8 a(9)
>
> in a(x)
>         2 
>         3 def a(x):
>   ----> 4     i = i +x
>         5     print (i)
>         6     pass
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing i = i + 2 you are actually referencing variable 'i' is referenced before its been assigned a value.

```
def a():
    i = i + 2 
    print (i)
    pass
```

In the below method variable 'total' is assigned a value. so you don get an error.

```
def sum(a,b):
   total = a+b
   print ("inner total is:",total)
return total
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer total variable is a global variable. Whereas the inner global variable only has scope inside that function sum(), which gives the error.

If you wish to make total globally accessible in your function then do the follows:

```
total = 0
def sum(a,b):
   global total
   total = a+b
   print ("inner total is:",total)
   return total 

sum(19,21)
print ("outer total is:",total)
```